# Тематика сайта, касающаяся серверов

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

В списке "онтопиков" есть такая фраза:

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений,
>   серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их
>   настройки, мониторинга и этих автоматизации процессов;

Как я понимаю, вопросы про железо сюда не входят (понимаю я это исключительно по реакции сообщества). Может быть следует уточнить формулировку и указать что вопросам про железо тут не место?

Comment: вам в этот вопрос: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1291/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Ну и почему же они должны быть не по теме? И вообще, что-то не заметно, чтобы этими списками кто-то руководствовался.

Comment: @Qwertiy Насчет назаметности - это плохо и по этому поводу уже была [идея](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1481) Лично я совсем не против железа (я вообще-то сисадмин), но местное сообщество почему-то его не очень любит

Comment: @tutankhamun, это не плохо. Плохо, что много народу пытаются позакрывать всё подряд. Чем больше лояльных проверяющих, тем лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме тематики есть и другие требования к вопросам. У вас есть пример вопроса про серверное железо, такой что:

- ответ будет полезен более чем одному человеку;
- можно дать объективно верный ответ, а не мнение;
- проблема воспроизводима?

Я был бы рад увидеть такой вопрос *про серверное железо* и ответы почитать. Только что-то таких не задают.

Я уже предлагал пару тем, которые могли бы на мой взгляд стать основой хороших ответов. Подкину ещё пару идей:

- Каким требованиям должно соответствовать сетевое оборудование для организации сети на 100 подключений по WiFi в одном большом рабочем помещении площадью 300 м2?
- Как организовать сбор, хранение и отображение диагностических данных по состоянию железа на серверах X с ОС Y? Можно ли прогнозировать поломки железа и по каким показателям это делать?

  А вот примеры вопросов "не очень":
- Есть N денег, какое железо мне купить?
- Где в городе K восстанавливают данные с хардов?
- Что-то сломалось, давайте вы зайдете по SSH и посмотрите.

Comment: Ну вот недавно был задан, ну не совсем чтобы очень хороший вопрос, но все таки. Речь шла о настройке железа и уживется ли в текущей концигурации на продакшне новый хард. Вопрос закрыли почти мгновенно, причем с формулировкой, что это оффтопик, так-как не про программирование. Я попытался намекнуть, что данная тема может быть не оффтопиком, но вопроса уже нет.

Comment: Продолжаем разговор... Я поэтому и поднял опять эту тему, может просто пойти на поводу у толпы и отказаться совсем от "железных" вопросов, чтобы даже сомнений не возникало?

Comment: @tutankhamun, а ссылку на вопрос дать?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я бы написал, но вопрос удален уже. С ним расправились быстрее чем со спамом

Comment: @tutankhamun Есть нюанс. Что у нас, что на Pt.SO, идею "Сайт SO+SF+SU должен быть един" активно и упорно проталкивает администрация, а большинство обычных юзеров против. Причём если у нас это противостояние выливается в войны открытий-закрытий, то на Pt.SO развернулась драма в нескольких частях: народ уже несколько раз собирал достаточно голосов на Зоне 51, чтобы открыть отдельный Pt.SF, и каждый раз администрация диктаторским решением закрывала предложение с аргументом "ибо нефиг". Что у нас творится — это цветочки. А на поводу толпы не пойдут, здесь её мнение никого не интересует.

Comment: @Discord: насколько я вижу, SF и SU и на английском-то чахлые. Думаете, наберется достаточно русскоязычных пользователей для этих же сайтов на русском?

Comment: @tutankhamun, тут вроде все удалённое смотреть могут. И на переоткрытие голосов собрать можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy: ну не все, а только начиная с 2000 репутации, насколько я помню. Это вы просто привыкли уже. )

Comment: @Qwertiy Cмотреть вроде тоже могу. Найти не могу. Может подскажете как по удаленным поискать? Я туда комментарий писал, в списке комментариев его тоже нет.

Comment: Может эту тему стОит обсудить в чате? А этот вопрос я удалю. И вообще есть-ли тут что обсуждать? Я вижу, с одной стороны, неприятие таких вопросов сообществом, с другой стороны, мнение что ничего не поменяется. Может это просто разговоры в пользу бедных?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Чахлые. И многие другие сайты Сети чахлые, про беты уж молчу. Вот поэтому администрация и хочет фармить траффик на одном сайте. Но достаточно большому числу юзеров (достаточному для регулярного закрытия вопросов) такая перспектива не улыбается.

Comment: @tutankhamun Поиск удалённых постов есть только у ромбов, насколько я понимаю. Вообще, можете заглянуть в https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- , можно обсудить.

Comment: @tutankhamun: в чат заходите, конечно. Что касается вопросов - я же говорю, вопросы про железо хочу, но конкретные и полезные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я имел в виду активных пользователей на мете. Не случайно же "тут" написал :)

Comment: @Discord Я нашел все-таки лазейку, как поискать среди удаленных. https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/queries

Comment: @tutankhamun Там нет удалённых постов, и вообще все данные изрядно вычищены.

Comment: @Discord Как это нету. Я же нашел. Вот тот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466387 Нашел по своему комментарию

Comment: @tutankhamun Там можно найти посты, которые были удалены на этой неделе, но существовали на предыдущей (обновление дампа по понедельникам, вроде). Соответственно, отловить можно исчезающе мало постов.

Comment: @tutankhamun, теперь он открытый удляённый))

Comment: @tutankhamun, а вообще, хм.. он же самим автором удалён.

Comment: @Discord там есть все удаленные посты. таблица `PostsWithDeleted` с `DeletionDate is not null`