# ¡[arduino] pasarán!

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

В связи с дискуссией под этим вопросом: [где найти заземление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487300/178576)

---

Понятно, что вопросы про arduino, касающиеся программной части — это «онтопик».

А как насчёт вопросов про arduino, касающихся «железной» части?

Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за один из ответов.

---

Также относится к теме обсуждения:

- [Куй [железо], пока тематика сайта ещё обсуждается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1291/178576)
- [Тематика сайта, касающаяся серверов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1764/178576)

Comment: В вариантах не хватает аргументации.)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ответы-то — общие. можно грабить корованы!

Comment: Я не понимаю тему вопроса. Видимо, это испанский, но я не понимаю смысл, и звучит неграмотно, как "[arduino] пройдут!"

Comment: @PeterOlson, [это выражение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD) ещё в советском союзе было весьма распространённой крылатой фразой (нынче говорят: «[мемом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC)»). да, то, что я написал в заголовке, скорее всего, безграмотно на любом языке. просто созвучно с «но пасаран», не более того.

Comment: @PeterOlson, я не имею ни малейшего представления, как склоняются глаголы в том языке, из которого взята эта крылатая фраза. заголовок — лишь чуть-чуть изменённая та самая крылатая фраза. если бы я изменил её больше, она стала бы менее узнаваемой.

Comment: @PeterOlson, между прочим, в русском языке предложенный вами перевод («ардуино пройдут») — звучит вполне грамотно, ибо слово «ардуино» не склоняется. по крайней мере, во множественном числе оно (грамотно) звучит точно так же: «у меня есть много ардуино» (просторечный вариант: «у меня есть много ардуин»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Извините, пожалуйста. Дело в том, что я знаю испанский, но не очень знаю советские фразы, но понимаю, что для других участников здесь скорее всего будет наоборот. Ну давай тогда обратно в кириллицу. Будет понятнее, что это - крылатая фраза, а не испанский текст.

Comment: @PeterOlson, в письменном представлении эта крылатая фраза знакома мне с детства **именно** в таком виде: «¡no pasarán!». я подозреваю, что вы — единственный здесь знаток испанского. прошу прощения за то, что составленный мною заголовок «режет вам глаз». тут у нас для вопросов про метки есть маленький обычай давать шутливый заголовок, не всегда укладывающийся в рамки грамотной речи. типа [такого](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1289/178576). предлагаю рассматривать ошибку в заголовке этой темы как некий стилистический приём типа анаколуфа, эрратива или чего-то в этом духе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну ладно, понятно. Простите меня за моё ненужное нытьё

Answer (score 28, accepted):

допустимы вопросы про arduino, касающиеся как программной, так и аппаратной части.

Comment: Ух, какая поддержка.

Answer (score 6):

допустимы вопросы про arduino, касающиеся только программной части.

Answer (score -9):

нет, никаких вопросов про arduino вообще не должно быть. ведь есть https://arduino.stackexchange.com/!